# wtforms not rendering form fields

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm having a problem rendering form fields using Flask and Wtforms. The input button is displayed but no fields to input data to the form. Here is the template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.name.label }}
{{ form.street_address.label }}
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

form code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class deed_of_trust_form(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()]),
    street_address = StringField('Street Address', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

and the route:

```
@app.route('/deed_of_trust', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def deed_of_trust():
    form = forms.deed_of_trust_form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Success!")
    return render_template('deed_of_trust.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're only showing the *label* of the form fields. You'll want to actually create the `<input>` fields as well from within your template

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name }} <br/>
    {{ form.street_address.label }} {{ form.street_address }} <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

See more detailed information in [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates).

Comment: Thank you.
Also, I had a comma after my first form field which was causing issues as well.